# Scala: keyword as package name

Tags: scala

I'm trying to use a Java library (no source code available) which defines some **xxx.xxx.object** package. Scala complains about the presence of "object" in the package name, so I can't import from it, and I can't refer to its classes with fully qualified name either.

Is there a way around it?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Wrapping the object in a ` (the quote next to 1) should work.

```
xxx.xxx.`object`
```

Comment: I'm noticing in 2.8.1.final that this still doesn't help you in the console -- probably a bug in the REPL code.  Importing works fine, but try to use one of the symbols you imported and apparently something doesn't get escaped in the background.

Answer (score 24):

To complete [agilefall](https://stackoverflow.com/users/101058/agilefall)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1215767/scala-keyword-as-package-name/1215941#1215941), the [**Scala Language Specification**](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/ScalaReference.pdf) mentions that an import is composed of `id`:

```
id ::= plainid
| ‘\`’ stringLit ‘\`’
```

> an identifier may also be formed by an arbitrary string between back-quotes (host systems may impose some restrictions on which strings are legal for identifiers). The identifier then is composed of all characters excluding the backquotes themselves.
>
> Backquote-enclosed strings are a solution when one needs to access Java identifiers that are reserved words in Scala.
>   For instance, the statement `Thread.yield()` is illegal, since `yield` is a reserved word in Scala. However, here’s a work-around:

```
Thread.`yield`()
```

Comment: Is there a more official name for it other than simply "back=quote enclosed strings"? Someone on #Scala mentioned "backtickling", but I can't find that in Google.

Comment: @AntonyStubbs "Programming in Scala" also mentions "back ticks" (for literal for instance)