# How to use Java package com.example...object in Scala

Tags: java, scala

How does one refer to a Java package including object in the name such as com.example.object in Scala?

Scala treats object as a reserved word and complains.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1215767/scala-keyword-as-package-name

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Put the reserved word inside backticks, like this:

```
com.example.`object`
```