# Is there a way to use "type" word as a variable name in Scala?

Tags: scala, keyword

It is frequent in my practice that a variable/argument is to store a type of something (as an enumeration value usually). And it usually makes no sense to specify an entity class in the name (like userType when a function is onlu intended to handle users). Is there a way I can use the "type" word for my needs instead of using scaffolds like "tipe", "kind", "somethingType" instead of it? The actual Scala `type` keyword is of such a rare use - it would be nice If I could undefine it (as a keyword) in the most of my code files.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use Java package com.example...object in Scala](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5088563/how-to-use-java-package-com-example-object-in-scala)

Answer (score 63):

You can escape with backticks:

```
val `type` = 5
```