# How to define column name that is Scala predefined

Tags: scala, cassandra, phantom-dsl

On Websudos Phantom DSL, how to define column name but it's already Scala's predefined variable, like `type`?

Example:

```
class MyTable extends CassandraTable[ConcreteValues, Value] {

  object id extends UUIDColumn(this) with PartitionKey[UUID]

  object type extends StringColumn(this) // <-- how to define this

}
```

How to define `type` column since it's already Scala's predefined variable?

Comment: You can generally use backticks for this - eg. `\`type\`` here.

Comment: Have you tried to use backticks?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to use "type" word as a variable name in Scala?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8198797/is-there-a-way-to-use-type-word-as-a-variable-name-in-scala)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As on question's comments said, generally it can be defined via `backticks`.
Thank you for the help guys.

Answer (score 1):

...or name your scala column to something legal and override the column-name mapping:

```
object somthingType extends StringColumn(this) {override lazy val name = "type"}
```