# How to access a Java object's field named "type" from Scala

Tags: scala, interop

I have an already existing class written in Java (lets say this class is called `X`) that contains a field / member named `type`.

I now want to write a Scala class / object that creates an object of type `X` and access the `type` member of that object.

Yet, since `type` is a keyword in Scala, this does not work. The error message in Eclipse is: `identifier expected but 'type' found.`

**Question:** Is it possible to access that field without renaming it?

---

A working example:

Java Class:

```
public class X {
  public final int type = 0;
}
```

Scala App:

```
object Playground extends App {
  val x : X = new X();
  System.out.println(x.type); // This does not work!
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either use backticks or define a gettter.

```
object Playground extends App {
  val x : X = new X();
  System.out.println(x.`type`)
}
```

Or using a getter,

```
public class X {
  public int type = 0;

  public int getType() {
    return type;
  }
}

object Playground extends App {
  val x : X = new X();
  System.out.println(x.getType());
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Since the fields are final in the original application (just edited the question), we didn't write getters on purpose, but good idea!

Comment: I don't like `Getter`s either, too much verbosity. `@Getter` for `static` variable  does not sound great though.

Answer (score 1):

You can use reserved words as names by using back ticks, e.g. `type`. For more information, see previous questions:
[Is there a way to use "type" word as a variable name in Scala?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8198797/is-there-a-way-to-use-type-word-as-a-variable-name-in-scala)