# Escaping scala reseverd word "type" in scala templete in play framework

Tags: java, scala, playframework-2.0

I'm just starting with playFramework with the intention on speeding up a web application development taking advantage of my background in Java. As Scala seems to be the most commmon option for the views in play, I decided to use it despite being new to it (and not intending to deepen into it, at least for now).

Well, I just figured out that "type" is a reserved word in scala, and though I've seen other Q&As such as [Is there a way to use "type" word as a variable name in Scala?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8198797/is-there-a-way-to-use-type-word-as-a-variable-name-in-scala) and [How to use Java package com.example...object in Scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5088563/how-to-use-java-package-com-example-object-in-scala?lq=1) saying that I just needed to add to enclose type with ` `

However, when I use the template code below:

```
<dl>
@for(alarm <- alarms){
  <dt>@alarm.id</dt>
  <dd>@alarm.`type`</dd>@* type is a scala keyword, so I had to escape it *@
  <dd>@form(routes.Application.deleteAlarm(alarm.id)) { <input type="submit" value="Delete"> }</dd>
}
</dl>
```

it outputs:

> models.Alarm@1.`type`

instead of the value of type.

How can I escape the keyword in this case?

Comment: I've taken that q&a in consideration... In fact, that answer is a duplicate of the 2 Q&As I mentioned above. The trick which I missed and that @serejja pointed out was that I needed to enclose the alarm.`type` in @{} on the play scala template

Comment: Oookay, not a dupe then, sorry.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Seems you are looking for this:

```
@{alarm.`type`}
```

Comment: That solves the problem! So the problem was that the template engine was closing the codeblock at the "." as the end of the scala codeblock was not strictly specified through the brackets?

Comment: It seems the template engine does not work well with `.`` combination, so you can help it by enclosing the block in curly braces