# Package namespaces in scala - and the reverse domain naming scheme

Tags: scala, akka

I have noticed that several TypeSafe affiliated projects like [spray](https://github.com/spray/spray) and [akka](https://github.com/akka/akka), do not include `com.` or `org.` as the beginning of the package names they define.

I wonder whether there are technical implications to this deviation from the "reverse domain" package naming scheme of Java. Is there any possible effect on java interoperability? What may be the technical implications of skipping the com/org constituent in scala package names in my own libraries and packages?

Of course, the reverse domain scheme alleviates the problem of package namespace collisions by linking the namespace to a resource uniquely dispensed by Internet registrars, so projects dismissing that model do not have that safeguard, but I would not strictly call that a *technical* implication, so we can ignore that...

Comment: BTW, http://docs.scala-lang.org/style/naming-conventions.html sort of recommends sticking to reverse domain naming but maybe it is outdated.

Comment: There is no technical compatibility concerns with scala not following the reverse domain guideline.. the same question of to follow it or not rises in Java too.  Generally the argument is that long package names suck and why waste time changing every source file every time a company changes its name verses the risk of clashing that you have already observed.

Comment: You already asked (and deleted) this question two days ago http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33190124/package-namespaces-in-scala-and-the-reverse-domain-naming-scheme

Comment: That is right. Because questions asked during the weekend are really never answered, it seemed like the only way to get the question answered. I don't find that bountying is a fair fit for that case, it is rather something for meta to solve imo.

Answer (score 0):

> the reverse domain scheme alleviates the problem of package namespace collisions

That's the only reason for the scheme, which should answer your question. The only issue for interoperability specifically in package structure that I'm aware of is the Scala package names can contain Java ([and Scala, using backticks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1215767/scala-keyword-as-package-name?rq=1)) keywords.

Comment: Although beyond the scope of question, can you briefly expand on the worst case interoperability scenario?

Comment: For this, it's simply that you can't access types in such a package from Java code (ignoring reflection).